# Is there a way to do matrix multiplication in Python but the items in the matrix are str instead of int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The question:

Suppose I have a 5 x 1 vector (array), and I want to make a square matrix by computing A*A^T, should look like this:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5],    
 [ 2  4  6  8 10],    
 [ 3  6  9 12 15],    
 [ 4  8 12 16 20],    
 [ 5 10 15 20 25]]
```

if the array is

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Is there a way to do the same as above but if the values in the array are strings instead of integers? So for instance,

`['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`.

The expected results would be

```
[[ 'aa'  'ae'  'ai'  'ao'  'au'],    
 [ 'ea'  'ee'  'ei'  'eo'  'eu'],    
 [ 'ia'  'ie'  'ii'  'io'  'iu'],    
 [ 'oa'  'oe'  'oi'  'oo'  'ou'],    
 [ 'ua'  'ue'  'ui'  'uo'  'uu']]
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: `np.tensordot` has some examples working with a object dtype array of strings.  But for strings, `astr*n` (with integer n) is repetition, and `astr1+astr2` is join.  No other "math" is defined for strings.

Comment: @Corralien just posted the expected outcome

Answer (score 1):

For object dtype array, we can take advantage of the string addition operator:

```
In [204]: x = np.array(['a','b','c'], object)
In [205]: np.add.outer(x,x)
Out[205]: 
array([['aa', 'ab', 'ac'],
       ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'],
       ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']], dtype=object)
In [206]: x[:,None]+x
Out[206]: 
array([['aa', 'ab', 'ac'],
       ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'],
       ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']], dtype=object)
```

Math on object dtype arrays delegates the action to methods of the objects.  So it is limited to the object's own methods.  For strings, simple addition is defined, as is multiply by an integer.